# Which google oauth playground API should I use to obtain a token with the name, user photo and email?

Tags: api, express, google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I found this tool from google recently https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
and well I am currently doing an authentication practice for an api with node and passpor.js, I would like to know which of these apis is the one that I should choose to obtain a token with the user, the email and the profile photo, in the tutorial I saw that use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, so I don't know if it is depreciated or has been replaced by a new one, or if it is something that can be used in production.

And well also if you could explain a little more about what this tool is, I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OAuth Playground you can "input your own scope".

Copy and paste `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` and click Authorize APIs.
Then exchange for an access token.

After that you can call `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo` and it should return the data you are looking for.